# auto-increment text_field number rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, textfield

i'v been researching trying to find the answer for this, but am struggeling to work it out. i have a booking_no text_field which i want to be automatically set when a user make a new booking through booking/new. i would like it to be an autonumber which just counts up by 1 evertime starting with 100.

I know it is probably easiest to do this in the model but i'm not sure how.

my booking.rb:
(i havent set the validates yet)

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :booking_no, :car_id, :date, :user_id

  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :user
end
```

EDIT for comment:

```
#error ArgumentsError in booking_controller#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

my booking_controller#create

```
def create
@booking = Booking.new(params[:booking])

respond_to do |format|
  if @booking.save
    format.html { redirect_to @booking, :notice => 'Booking was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @booking, :status => :created, :location => @booking }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @booking.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: please add line no. where you got error...

Comment: pls check my updated callback method in answer for null case handling...

Comment: there is no line number on new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best if you set the `booking_no` as auto-increment field in the Database table itself..

Otherwise to manage it in your model, you can proceed something like:

```
before_create :increment_booking_no

def increment_booking_no
    self.booking_no = (self.class.last.nil?) ? "0" : ((self.class.last.booking_no.to_i) + 1).to_s
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I decided to use the model method. i get an error from my controller now. ill upload the error

Comment: it worked for the first booking. but i tried another booking and got another error... ill update the post

Comment: updated post.. check the error might have been resolved if it was for wrong no. of arguments at this line

Comment: that works, however it doesnt change the string now. it add +1 to the end of the string. example, 01. 011, 0111

Comment: i have updated the answer...use same.. and please try to handle these small logical changes/ syntactical changes by yourself...

Comment: im back to "can't convert Fixnum into String"